# printing special characters in awk output

Tags: shell-script, awk, aix, special-characters, split

I have a large file that contains lot MQ messages with RFH2 header. Each message in the file is separated by a blank line. Now I need to split this large file into small files each containing single message with RFH2 header.

I tried with the below awk command

`awk '{RS=""} {print $0}' inputfile`

This prints the first line without the control characters which is not useful. The first MQ RFH header line starts like `RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR   ^D¸` followed by message data. The awk output only prints the text `RFH`. If the input file has 50 messages after running this command I get 50 files having only the text `RFH` in them. I am expecting 50 files with RFH2 header and data.

I could not give you the real file input because it has sensitive data. The file starts with

```
RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^D¸X<jms>
.........some text of many lines.....

RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^D¸X<jms>
........some text of many lines.....

RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^D¸X<jms>
...
```

And the output files should have

```
RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^D¸X<jms>
.........some text of many lines
```

Comment: Can you give some real input?

Comment: Hi Gnouc - I could not give you the real file input because it has sensitive data. The file starts with "RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR   ^D¸X<jms>.........some text of many lines.....blank line...RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR   ^D¸X<jms>........some text of many lines.....blank line...RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR   ^D¸X<jms>...". Let me know if this gives you an idea..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Added the comment to question

Comment: it's so hard to understand your example, it may be because of formatting.

Comment: Does the file contain _actual_ control characters (octal values \002,\003,\030 and so on) or _ASCII representations_ of control characters (literal carat-B, carat-C etc.)?

Comment: Do you need only to separate by blank lines or also by spaces? Using `RS=""` would lead you to that output that you have mentioned, as by default Record Separator is defined for `\n` (newline).

Comment: @steeldriver the characters are mentioned as control characters

Comment: @AleksanderKseniya Yes, I need to split it only by blank lines

Comment: What platform are you on (GNU/Linux? BSD?). Are you sure it is not a matter of your terminal not being able to display the control characters? What happens if you pipe the output to a hex viewer e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}; {print $0}' file | xxd`? BTW you probably need your `RS` assignment to be in a `BEGIN` block to achieve the desired splitting.

Comment: @steeldriver I am on Aix 6.1 platform and I am sure its not the problem of terminal, because I can see the characters in input file but not in the output file

Comment: Sorry - I can't help you then. It seems to work fine with both GNU awk and mawk.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Input (testfile):

```
RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^DÂ¸X<jms>
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....

RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^DÂ¸X<jms>
........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....

RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^DÂ¸X<jms>
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
```

Code:

`awk '{print $0 > "file" NR}' RS='\n\n' testfile`

Replace "file" with the name of the files that you want to have. With this example, you'll have:

```
$ cat file1
RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^DÂ¸X<jms>
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....

$ cat file2
RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^DÂ¸X<jms>
........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....

$ cat file3
RFH ^B^C^X^A^Q^C3MQSTR ^DÂ¸X<jms>
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
.........some text of many lines.....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is close:

```
awk '{RS=""} {print $0}' inputfile
```

However, you need to define the RS variable *before* awk starts reading the file. Choose one of these:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""} {print}' inputfile
awk -v RS="" '{print}' inputfile
```

To view the control characters, pipe the awk output into `cat -v`

```
awk -v RS="" 1 inputfile | cat -v
```